# How to use spider in Burp through ZAP?

Tags: proxy, owasp, zap, penetration-testing, burp

Burp Community Edition from version 2.x doesn't have the scanning/spidering as a free option.

Is it possible to use spidering in Burp Community Edition using ZAP as a proxy?

Comment: Out of interest is there any reason why you dont just use ZAP? It should have all of the functionality available in Burp Community Edition...

Comment: I am slightly more familiar with Burp and I wasn't aware of all ZAP functionalities. I'm still learning about those.

Comment: We have lots of videos here : https://www.zaproxy.org/videos/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open ZAP and go to `Options > Local Proxies` and set it to **localhost:8081** (for example).
2. Go to Firefox Connection Settings and set up the proxy for the same port:

[image: Firefox proxy settings]

3. Start Burp Community Edition and go to `Proxy > Options` tab and verify Burp is listening at **localhost:8080**

[image: Burp proxy settings]

4. Now go back to ZAP and in `Options > Connection > Use Proxy Chain` check `Use an outgoing proxy server` and fill in the Burp's port settings:

[image: ZAP Connection settings]

5. If you now visit the target page in Firefox, it will show up in both ZAP and Burp dashboards. But now you can use ZAP's crawling option by right clicking the site and selecting Attack > Spider and the resulting pages will show up in Burp as well.

Credit: found it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CJB8BtW0pQ&t=331s).